Age discrimination or not
I applied for a position that was a great match for my skills. I was told it looked like it was written for me. The interview conductor I knew, said it went well.
7 weeks later and I get an "I’m sorry" letter. No one, including HR wants to answer what happened. So I asked HR is it age discrimination and they panic. The new guy is younger. Doesn’t know programming or databases and didn’t match the job description.
I’m at a dead end in my current position and the new on had a large potential for pay increase.
Not sure of the next steps.

The reason why HR doesn't reply is very boring and bland.  There's no benefit to them to reply why, and if they make a mistake in replying why, others can then use the letter as proof of their incompetence or wrong doing in the eyes of the public.

How do you know the new hire doesn't know programming/databases? As someone who didn't get the job in the past. I never knew the qualifications of the person they hired instead of me.

I asked the hiring manager directly.

Maybe the other person is getting paid much less than you would and the company is willing to train them on the job.  That's not age discrimination, just a financial decision.

As an older member of the technical workforce, I know that if I were to try to change jobs, I might be priced right out of the market.  You and I can't fault the employer for deciding that price is too high(if that is what happened).

I work for a utility and if this is as a union job posting and they just hired anyone, the union would scream. I’m in mgt nonunion and I’m the only one who does that his programming. With years of experience I was surprised. I inquired but was stonewalled. So I pushed back. They meet with me and asked for time to look into it. We get 4 hours of discrimination training a year and I have options. Meanwhile I’m looking elsewhere. I like the answers, some are helpful, some not so but thank you.

It wasn’t a price thing, the new position range was $10-70k a year more than my current position.

“The new guy is younger. Doesn’t know programming or databases and didn’t match the job description.” - How do you know the age and experience level of the individual they selected and do you know if they were hired for an equivalent role or perhaps simply hired for a lesser role in lieu of

@BillChappell It costs nothing to talk with a lawyer, and given that you have many facts on your side, I would highly recommend doing so.  Given your comments this "smells fishy" and that is often good enough for a decent settlement out of court.

Maybe they did discriminate against you. What do you want to have happen now, force them to hire you so you can spend every day with them?

I don't think contacting them and throwing out baseless accusations will ever help you in any case. Doing this often will hurt you a lot in the long run.

Can you prove age discrimination? Did they say so (preferably in writing) or do you have someone on the inside that can confirm that?
If that is the case, get a lawyer, and let them check which laws were violated and what your next steps could be.
If not, the explanation might be much, much simpler: the younger, less experienced guy probably earns half of your salary. They might just be cheap. There is not a lot you can do about it. That is not discrimination.
Either way, you didn't get the job. Continue looking. Focus on moving forward, don't spent your energy looking backwards.

You might not have considered the impact of your words, I can guarantee you that the company will no longer consider you.  Companies don't hire employees that casually mention they might be curious about suing the company.
And if you want to pursue that route, you should be talking to a lawyer, not the company.
And if you are unaware of what such a comment would do to a HR department, maybe you have the technical skills, but are lacking the social skills / corporate awareness that they seek (regardless of your age).
They're now forumating plans to defend against a possible lawsuit.
The reason why HR doesn't reply is very boring and bland. There's no benefit to them to reply why, and if they make a mistake in replying why they didn't choose a specific candidate; and if their reply has any misstep, others can then use the letter as proof of their incompetence or wrongdoing.


So I asked HR is it age discrimination and they panic.

You toss a threat their way and they don't want to talk nice with you. Go figure.
If you want to sue, talk to a lawyer. Otherwise put this behind you and move on. Stop with the threats.
I once had a perpetually unhappy worker on my team complain to me that she thought some people in a different department were discriminating against her because of her race. I immediately went to HR and got them involved. Fortunately, she quit soon after. I suspect it was better for everyone that way.


I was told it looked like it was written for me. The interview
conductor I knew, said it went well.

I have interviewed hundreds of people and 100% of the people I wanted to keep interested heard the same line from me. It is meaningless. It is a throw away line.

7 weeks later and I get an I’m sorry letter.

Very few people even get this.

I’m at a dead end in my current position and the new on had a large
potential for pay increase.

Keep applying. Keep interviewing. During those 7 weeks you should have reached out to dozens of companies.
There is no benefit from reaching out repeatably to HR, or in implying you will sue them. They have zero obligation to justify their choice to you. In fact they may not have been the one to make the choice.


No one, including HR wants to answer what happened

It could be that there is a good explanation but that HR would be embarrassed to provide it. Like maybe you have the technical skills, but you're kind of a jerk and everyone hates working with you. And HR just doesn't want to come out and say "sorry but you're kind of a ****"
Or it could be discrimination like you suspect
There is no way that we can tell from the little information provided

So I asked HR is it age discrimination and they panic.

Well of course they panicked. Whether or not it was discrimination, they are now afraid you are going to sue them. Even if they are completely innocent of discrimination, being accused of it and being drug through litigation is going to be a big pain for them. Of course they would react this way

Not sure of the next steps

If you really think it is discrimination talk to an employment attorney

I feel this only restates/rehashes what  is said in the other two answers (the reason can be any, not really worth to break your head on that, the age discr. may triggered them, talk to lawyer). Can you try to enhance or provide new insights or solutions to OP?

@DarkCygnus well look I know you are just improve the quality of answers, but, if you check the timestamps, you'll see that my answer was posted within a few minutes of some other answers, not 3 days later.  When I started typing my answer, there were zero other answers.  After I posted it, I saw that some other answers had been posted while I was typing. So I was not rehashing something that I had already read. It was my own original thought. I just typed a little slower than the other guy. We all independently came up with the same answer.

Yeah exactly, I looked at timestamps before writing the comment, and saw a 10+ min difference between them, so I was in limbo if you were typing and writing as the others posted or if you just didnt read or rehash (with some tendency towards "op didnt read the other answers" to be honest, due to the 10+ minutes). And yes, my goal with my comment was to bring this to your attention and try to improve the post and help OP more :) thank you for clarifying your POV and reasoning. (This has happened to me many times, simultaneous posts that is, and most of them I end up deleting my answer)

Why would you immediately jump to "age discrimination"? Why would you ask them that? Did you think they would admit to it?

"You caught us. We discriminated against you because of your age. I
guess you'll probably sue us now. See you in court!"

They would never admit it, and you could most probably never prove it. Any chance you had with them is now gone. Your next step is to move on and pursue other opportunities.
